# I have tried to implement mergesort and am unable to find the exact problem of my code. The program shows no errors but I do not get a desired output

Tags: c++, recursion, mergesort

Tried implementing mergesort, below is code. Let me know if anything is wrong.
Is there any any error in my merge function? unable to point to the exact problem in my code. Any help regarding the same would be highly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Merge function to merge the two sorted arrays

```
void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int end) {
    int n1 = mid - start + 1;
    int n2 = end - mid;
    
    int arr1[n1], arr2[n2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        arr1[i] = arr[start + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        arr2[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
    }

    int i;
    int j;
    int p;
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    p = start;
    
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j]) {
            arr[p] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[p] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        p++;
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[p] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        p++;
    }

    while (j < n2) {
        arr[p] = arr2[j];
        i++;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Calling mergesort recursively

```
void merge_sort(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
      return;
    }
    if (start < end) {
        int mid = start + (end - 1) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, start, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}
```

Print function to print the array

```
void printArray(int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Main function

```
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 6, 5, 12, 10, 9, 1 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    merge_sort(arr, 0, n - 1);
    cout << "The sorted array is: " << endl;
    printArray(arr, n);
}
```

Comment: Automatic allocations of arbitrarily sized arrays (eg `int arr1[n1], arr2[n2];`) in a recursive function Is a recipe for Stack Overflow. Automatic allocation of arrays in a recursive function even if the size is known can be iffy, but at least you can precompute a maximum depth you can handle before running out of storage. That said, with six elements in the array, you're probably safe.

Comment: According to gdb, in `arr[p] = arr2[j];` `p` got to 262272. Might want to run down how that happened. Looks like it might have something to do with `while (j < n2)` and nothing inside the loop changing the value of `j`. `i++;` -> `j++;`? Stuff like that is why I hate-hate-hate single letter variable names, by the way.

Comment: Tip: In C++ use `std::vector` for variable-length arrays.

Comment: Discuss `int mid = start + (end - 1) / 2;` with [your Rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 bugs is the code:

- computing the mid point as `int mid = start + (end - 1) / 2;` is incorrect. You should instead write:

  ```
    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
  ```
- in the last loop in `merge` you increment `i` instead of `j`. Note that this loop is redundant as the remaining elements of `arr2` are already at the end of `arr`.

You follow the classic convention in mergesort implementations where `end` is the index of the last element in the slice. This convention requires multiple `+1` / `-1` adjustments, it easy to get it wrong.

In C and related languages where array indices start at `0`, it is more idiomatic to use a different convention: passing `start` as the index of the first element of the slice and `end` as the index just past the last element. This allows to specify empty splices and produces cleaner code.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Merge function to merge the two sorted arrays
void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int end) {
    int n1 = mid - start;
    int n2 = end - mid;
    int arr1[n1], arr2[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        arr1[i] = arr[start + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
        arr2[j] = arr[mid + j];
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int p = start;
    
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
        if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j]) {
            arr[p] = arr1[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[p] = arr2[j];
            j++;
        }
        p++;
    }
    while (i < n1) {
        arr[p] = arr1[i];
        i++;
        p++;
    }
    // the remaining elements from `arr2` are already in place in `arr`
}

// Calling mergesort recursively
void merge_sort(int arr[], int start, int end) {
    if (end - start > 1) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
        merge_sort(arr, start, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

// Print function to print the array
void printArray(const int arr[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

// Main function
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 6, 5, 12, 10, 9, 1 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
    merge_sort(arr, 0, n);
    cout << "The sorted array is: " << endl;
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```